# When I select a item it doesn't do anything?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $group_name = <STDIN>;
my $group_id = <STDIN>;
my $choice = <STDIN>;

print "* My menu *\n";
print "* *\n";
print "* 1. Create a Unix Group  *\n";
print "* 2. Delete a Unix Group  *\n";
print "* 3. Create a Unix User *\n";
print "* 4. Delete a Unix USer *\n";
print "* 5. Quit *\n";
print "* *\n";
print "******************************************************\n";
print "* Enter Your Choice >\n";

$choice = <STDIN> ;

chomp $choice;
if ($choice == 1) {
print "**********************************\n";
print " Create A Unix Group\n";
print "**********************************\n";
print " Enter The Group Name to Create >\n";
chomp ($group_name = <STDIN>);
print " Enter the Group ID to Create >\n";
chomp ($group_id = <STDIN> );

if ( ! `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` ) {
   system ("/usr/bin/groupadd -g $group_id $group_name");
print "Group Created Successfully!\n"
   } else {
print "Group Already Exists !\n";
   }

chomp $choice;
if ($choice == 2) {
print "**********************************\n";
print " Delete a Unix Group\n";
print "**********************************\n";
print " Enter a Group Name to Delete >\n";
chomp ($group_name = <STDIN>);

if ( ! `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` ) {
   system ("/usr/bin/groupdel -g $group_id $group_name");
print "Delete Group Successfully!\n"
   } else {
print "Group Doesn't Exist !\n";
   }

}   
}
```

When I select the select number "2" which is called "Delete a Unix Group" it doesn't do anything. All it does is return me to the command line? What I'm missing?

Comment: Why are you reading into `$group_name` `$group_id` and `$choice` at the top of the script and then reading into them again at the appropriate time within the script?  You also appear to be `chomp`ing `$choice` twice.

Comment: any suggestions? Anything I change? The reason I have them at the top is because I need to use variables or else the script won't run? I'm open to any suggestions to improve it

Comment: If you want to declare them as global to the script, you can declare them at the top without assigning a value from `STDIN`.  So, just call `my $group_name;`. However, that's not really necessary given the code you have, and you can keep them scoped to the conditional block.  So, you can change line 29 to something like `chomp( my $group_name = <STDIN> );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block that is supposed to execute when 2 is selected is *inside* the block for when 1 is selected. Try deleting one of the right braces at the end and adding one before the block for when 2 is selected.

```
chomp $choice;
if ($choice == 1) {
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Create A Unix Group\n";
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Enter The Group Name to Create >\n";
  chomp ($group_name = <STDIN>);
  print " Enter the Group ID to Create >\n";
  chomp ($group_id = <STDIN> );

  if ( ! `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` ) {
    system ("/usr/bin/groupadd -g $group_id $group_name");
    print "Group Created Successfully!\n"
  } else {
    print "Group Already Exists !\n";
  }
}

#chomp $choice;    <-- This chomp is superfluous; you already removed the newline
elsif ($choice == 2) {
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Delete a Unix Group\n";
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Enter a Group Name to Delete >\n";
  chomp ($group_name = <STDIN>);

  if ( ! `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` ) {
    system ("/usr/bin/groupdel -g $group_id $group_name");
    print "Delete Group Successfully!\n"
  } else {
    print "Group Doesn't Exist !\n";
  }
}
```

Using indentation can help catch this sort of thing in the future.

Comment: I added a mention that the second chomp is superfluous.

Comment: Oh yeah is my variables alright or do I need to change them? since someone stated why I have those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the "if ($choice == 1)" block includes the "if ($choice == 2)" block, which means that the "if ($choice == 2)" statement will only be executed if $choice is 1; and, of course, if $choice == 1, the "if ($choice == 2)" block will not be be executed.  If choice is 2, the next instruction after "if ($choice == 1)" is the program termination.

Bottom line: Restructure your if... blocks to reflect what you intend; and after you do that, you might want to change "if ($choice == 2)" to use elsif - which has the same function and, IMO, is clearer.

Also, change the initialization at the top to get rid of the '= STDIN'; you don't want to read from stdin at that point.